# COUNT evaluate to zero if no matching records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Take the following:

```
SELECT 
    Count(a.record_id) AS newrecruits
    ,a.studyrecord_id
FROM 
    visits AS a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        record_id
        , MAX(modtime) AS latest 
    FROM 
        visits 
    GROUP BY 
        record_id
)  AS b 
ON (a.record_id = b.record_id) AND (a.modtime = b.latest)
WHERE (((a.visit_type_id)=1))
GROUP BY a.studyrecord_id;
```

I want to amend the `COUNT` part to display a zero if there are no records since I assume `COUNT` will evaluate to `Null`.

I have tried the following but still get no results:

```
IIF(ISNULL(COUNT(a.record_id)),0,COUNT(a.record_id)) AS newrecruits
```

Is this an issue because the join is on `record_id`? I tried changing the `INNER` to `LEFT` but also received no results.

**Q**
How do I get the above to evaluate to zero if there are no records matching the criteria?

**Edit:**

To give a little detail to the reasoning.

The studies table contains a field called 'original_recruits' based on activity before use of the database.

The visits tables tracks new_recruits (Count of records for each study).

I combine these in another query (original_recruits + new_recruits)- If there have been no new recruits I still need to display the original_recruits so if there are no records I need it to evalulate to zero instead of null so the final sum still works.

Comment: Your query seems missing commas. Please post query which can be compiled.

Comment: Why are you joining to the sub-query at all, when your results are not dependent on it? Also, do you have a separate table holding studyrecord details?

Comment: Added comma. The table contains multiple instances of the same record to track changes - the subquery selects the latest edit date/time and so the most up to date version of the record.Yes studyrecord details held in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by amending the final query where I display the result of combining the original and new recruits to include the `IIF` there.

```
SELECT
    a.*
    , IIF(IsNull([totalrecruits]),consents,totalrecruits)/a.target AS prog
    , IIf(IsNull([totalrecruits]),consents,totalrecruits) AS trecruits
FROM
    q_latest_studies AS a
LEFT JOIN q_totalrecruitment AS b
ON a.studyrecord_id=b.studyrecord_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to count records by StudyRecords.
If you need a count of zero when you have no records, you need to join to a table named StudyRecords.
Did you have one? Else this is a nonsense to ask for rows when you don't have rows!

Let's suppose the StudyRecords exists, then the query should look like something like this :

```
SELECT 
    Count(a.record_id) AS newrecruits -- a.record_id will be null if there is zero count for a studyrecord, else will contain the id
    sr.Id
FROM 
    visits AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            record_id
            , MAX(modtime) AS latest 
        FROM 
            visits 
        GROUP BY 
            record_id
    )  AS b 
    ON (a.record_id = b.record_id) AND (a.modtime = b.latest)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN studyrecord sr
        ON sr.Id = a.studyrecord_id
WHERE a.visit_type_id = 1
GROUP BY sr.Id
```

Comment: I added some more explanation to my original question.